# Creating a More Complex Login Page.. Which Membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, membership

I want to two steps on my login screen, UserGroup and UserName like;

Group A

- UserID=1 Username=ahmet
- UserID=2 Username=mehmet, name=mehmet, surname=demir
- UserID=3 Username=ali, name=ali, surname=bakır

Group B

- UserID=4 Username=veli
- UserID=5 Username=mehmet, name=mehmet, surname=çelik
- UserID=6 Username=ali, name=ali, surname=pirinç

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dasj.png

When Mehmet Demir wants to login, he has to use aGroup, mehmet and his password,
When Mehmet Çelik wants to login, he has to use bGroup, mehmet and his password..

**Which Membership I have to use??**

I try to use ASP.NET SimpleMembership;
My database diagram is;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVpKp.png

and I try like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (model.UserGroupName != null)
        {
            UsersContext userContext = new UsersContext();
            DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
            var userGroupName = model.UserGroupName;
            var userGroupID = db.UserGroups.Where(a => a.UserGroupName == userGroupName).Select(b => b.UserGroupID).Single();
            var userName = userContext.UserProfiles.Where(c => c.UserGroupID == userGroupID).Select(d => d.UserName);

            if (userName.Contains(model.UserName))
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }


        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "User group, username or password is incorrect..");
        return View(model);
    }
```

It works but when I want to create new user of course i cant register same username in different user group..

How can I customize SimpleMembership account controller or account models?? **Or Using another Membership??**

Answer (score 0):

I might not have understood your question correctly. If you want to register same username with multiple groups you would need to a different database design. You will need to create a mapping table for example UsersInGroups that will have UserId and GroupId. That way your users can have multiple groups associated with them.

You then can query that table, get all records for the userid and get all associated groups and compare if it matches inputted group.